# RxJS 5 with Angular 2: replay subscription on schedule determined by previous result

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

In my `Angular 2` `typescript 2` app, I query the server for a value that needs to be updated periodically.  The delay between updates is variable (the server sends an expiration date along with the value).

I'm having trouble composing an Observable stream that will replay (initiate a new call to the server) automatically once the current value reaches expiration.  What I have so far doesn't scale at all:

```
price = 5; //initial value is known
expires = ...;//initial expiration is known

getData(){
    // server returns {expires:number, price:number}
    this.http.get('...').map(res => res.json())
}

Observable.timer(expires-Date.now()) // when initial price expires
    .switchMap(()=>this.getData()) // fetch new price and expiration
    .subscribe( data =>
        {
            this.price = data.price;
            Observable.timer(data.expires-Date.now()) //redo when price expires
                .switchMap(()=>getData())
                .subscribe(...) //callback hell (endless inner blocks)
        }
    );
```

There must be a better way to schedule the follow-up calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach was to use `switchMap()` along with `timer()` to delay the start of the observable chain, and `repeat()` to keep seeking fresh data once the previous price expires:

```
price = 0;    //initial price
_exp  = 0; //initial delay before fetching data

/** Observable will emit after the expiration delay */
wait() {return Observable.timer(this._exp*1000)}

stream$ = Observable.of(null)
    .switchMap(()=>this.wait()) // wait for the expiration delay                
    .switchMap(()=>this.getServerData()) // get fresh data
    .do(e=>{this._exp = e.expires}) //update expiration             
    .repeat() // repeat until the calling code unsubscribes
```

When I subscribe, the first price is fetched immediately, and the sequence is repeated indefinitely with each cycle delayed by `expires` seconds. I can update the model with prices as they arrive:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.stream$.subscribe( e=>this.price = e.price);
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XElPOY3MzkrJyJOlrH5X?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

call doObservableStuff initially when ever it is necessory

```
getData(){
    // server returns {expires:number, price:number}
    this.http.get('...').map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe( data =>
        {
            this.price = data.price;
            doObservableStuff(data.expires-Date.now())
        });
}

doObservableStuff(time){
    Observable.timer(time)
    .switchMap(() => this.getData())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the creative solution.  The `getData()` is actually in a different service (`DataService`) that the current module relies on and other modules rely on the same `getData()`, so I don't want to call `doObservableStuff()` from that method, and that method is not in the same scope as `this.price`; the two methods should be in independent contexts.